# Printing rows of increasing amounts of even numbers

Tags: java, numbers

I'm trying to print the following:

```
2
2 4
2 4 6 ..etc
```

The code I have written (below) prints the following:

```
2
4 6
8 10 12 ...etc
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? The n variable comes from the main method which I am not including.

```
public static void printEvenTable(int n) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print(" " + (k += 2));
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialization of `k` is currently outside your loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, the inner loop is increasing the variable `k` by `2` in each steps after the first execution of the inner loop `k` becomes `2` from the initial value `0`. In the second iteration of the outer loop `k` starts as `2`. After `k+=2`, `k` becomes `4` so second line of output starts from `4`. That's why we need to re-initialize k to `0` before each inner loop.

```
public static void printEvenTable(int n) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
         k = 0;
         for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print(" " + (k += 2));


        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks. For my own understanding could you please explain why that change was required?

Comment: @JEarls I've explained. Pls, check the edit. And, if it helps feel free to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the variable `k` from using its old value by reassigning 0 to it right after the second `for` loop. Placing `k = 0;` before the second `for` loop makes redundant reassigning because it has already been assigned right before the loop. Ensure program optimization. If you are using a good editor, it show you some warning if placed before the second `for` loop.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
         System.out.print(" " + (k += 2));
     }
     k=0;
     System.out.println(" ");
}
```